# Override array.push Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

First off the code below can't happen due to a recursive infinite loop. I am trying to override the push function on an array. Using Coffeescript I want to be able to push in objects that have ID's and make sure they are unique before adding them to the array. The problem is that I can't find what variable I should be adding this object to.

How do I add the object to the super Array?

```
class SpecialArray extends Array
  Array::push = (arg) ->
    added = $.grep @, (item) ->
        if item
           item.id == arg.id
    if added <= 0
      @push.call(@,arg) // won't work due to loop
```

The error that I am getting when I run this piece of code:
[image]

Comment: What loop? Also, were you looking for `added.length`?

Comment: You [cannot extend `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array).

Comment: @Bergi I could see how it causes problems. I was able to figure out that just creating another method and then calling push at the end instead of overriding works. I still wanted the functionality Array, I just needed to add additional functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never overwrite `Array::push`. In your case, you're even calling it recursively.

I think you're looking for

```
class SpecialArray extends Array
  constructor: () ->
    ref = super
    ref.push = push
    ref
  push = (arg) ->
    unless !arg.id or arg.id in (item.id for item in @)
      Array::push arg
```

([compile](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20SpecialArray%20extends%20Array%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20ref%20%3D%20super%0A%20%20%20%20ref.push%20%3D%20push%0A%20%20%20%20ref%0A%20%20push%20%3D%20%28arg%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20arg.id%20and%20arg.id%20not%20in%20%28item.id%20for%20item%20in%20%40%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Array%3A%3Apush%20arg))

Notice that however `new SpecialArray` is not `instanceof SpecialArray`, but a plain `Array`, and it's overwritten `push` method doesn't handle multiple arguments.

Comment: @LieuweRooijakkers: Thanks for the edit suggestion, but I really meant assignment not prototype method declaration. The `super` seems to have been working there in previous CoffeeScript versions.